# angular cdk drag drop - is there any way to async validate on drop and revert if validation returns false?

Tags: angular, angular-cdk, angular-dragdrop

When droping an item I want to be able to perform an async call (e.g. check with backend for conflicts, collisions and so forth...) which returns true or false. If false, I want to "reverse" the drop so that the item appears in the original array.

I coulnd't find any references in the offical docs, so any pointers are appreciated on how to tackle this challenge.

Comment: on `CdkDragDrop` event you will push into array then you want to make call and check if it returns `false` remove item from new array as you will have index `event.currentIndex` of item in new array and push it into old array you have previous index as well `event.previousIndex`.

Comment: From Angular material example, if you want to call `moveItemInArray(this.timePeriods, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);` it will sort the position within your array. Maybe if you only call this after receive a success from your API.

Comment: @Imarcelocc `event` will also give correct positions for different different arrays

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for this, here's *one* way to do it. It would be great if the move could somehow be told to wait for the result before reverting, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

```
try{
//Move the value first
transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
  event.container.data,
  event.previousIndex,
  event.currentIndex);

//Wait for the result and then roll back the change if required
this.openEdit(event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]).subscribe((result:Updated) =>
  {

    if(result?.success !== 1){
      transferArrayItem(event.container.data,
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.currentIndex,
        event.previousIndex);
    }

  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea proposed by @Jim, a possible solution can be simply do the change and asynchronously check the status of the operation, if it is ok: done, otherwise revert the change, the following solution will work also using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`

```
transferArrayItem(
    event.previousContainer.data,
    event.container.data,
    event.previousIndex,
    event.currentIndex);

this.service.asyncItem(itemToUpdate).toPromise().catch(() => {
    transferArrayItem(
          event.container.data,
          event.previousContainer.data,
          event.currentIndex,
          event.previousIndex);

    this.cdr.detectChanges();
});
```